# Issue - Tkinter need to check if a value in entry box is already in a specific column in my sqlite database table

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

i am new in this community, i am trying to lear python (my version is 3.7 for windows 10)

i have created this program (i will attach the code below) with python / Tkinter

here is where i am stuck:

When the user push "Submit" button, i need to check if the entry box "Assignment number" (if you launch the program, it is on the top of the GUI) already exist on my sqlite3 table before inserting all the data that the user submitted will be stored in the database

Basically i need that each survey submitted have a unique Assignment number

If you could help would be great (haven't sleep in a week)

Thank you in advance for all your help

```
import backend
import csv
from backend import write_to_csv
import os
from Send_email_gui import send_email
from backend import check_assignment


def add_entry_command():
    #check_assignment_no.check_assignment(assignment_no_text.get())
    if check_assignment(assignment_no_text.get())== 0:
        backend.insert(client_code_text.get(), client_name_text.get(), assignment_no_text.get(), accountant_text.get(), year_end_text.get(), file_presentation_text.get(), quality_of_job_processed_text.get(), queries_text.get(), indexing_text.get(), final_reports_text.get(), documents_handling_text.get(), meeting_deadlines_text.get(), communication_text.get(), analytical_review_text.get(), overall_job_text.get(), suggestion_text.get())
        send_email(accountant_text, client_code_text, client_name_text, assignment_no_text, year_end_text, file_presentation_text, quality_of_job_processed_text, queries_text, indexing_text, final_reports_text, documents_handling_text, meeting_deadlines_text, communication_text, analytical_review_text, overall_job_text, suggestion_text)
        messagebox.showinfo('Confirmation', 'Thank you for your submission, click ok and close')        
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo('Assignment number used', 'Assignment number already used, please check again and submit')

def __init__(self, assignment_no_, accountant_, year_end_, client_code_, client_name_, file_presentation_, quality_of_job_processed_, queries_, 
    indexing_, final_reports_, documents_handling_, meeting_deadlines_, communication_, analytical_review_, overall_rate_, suggestion_):
        self.assignment_no_=assignment_no_
        self.accountant_=accountant_
        self.year_end_=year_end_
        sel.client_code_=client_code_
        self.client_name_=client_name_
        self.file_presentation_=file_presentation_
        self.quality_job_=quality_of_job_processed_
        self.queries_assumptions_=queries_
        self.indexing_cross_ref_=indexing_
        self.final_reports_=final_reports_
        self.doc_handling_=documents_handling_
        self.meet_deadlines_=meeting_deadlines_
        self.communi_=communication_
        self.analytical_rev_=analytical_review_
        self.overall_rate_=overall_rate_
        self.suggestion_box_=suggestion_



window=Tk()

"""
Center the window of the program
"""
# Gets the requested values of the height and widht.
windowWidth = window.winfo_reqwidth()
windowHeight = window.winfo_reqheight()
#print("Width",windowWidth,"Height",windowHeight)

# Gets both half the screen width/height and window width/height
positionRight = int(window.winfo_screenwidth()/6 - windowWidth/6)
positionDown = int(window.winfo_screenheight()/6 - windowHeight/6)

# Positions the window in the center of the page.
window.geometry("+{}+{}".format(positionRight, positionDown))

"""
Top data entry level 
TO DO - build function to return client name directly from Iris database - build button
"""

label_title=Label(window, text="Global Infosys feedback collector", height=3, fg="blue", font=(20))
label_title.grid(row=0, column=2)

l1=Label(window, text="Client code")
l1.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky='E')

l2=Label(window, text="Client name")
l2.grid(row=4, column=3, sticky='E')



l3=Label(window, text="Assignment no:")
l3.grid(row=5, column=1, sticky='E')

l4=Label(window, text="Accountant:")
l4.grid(row=6, column=1, sticky='E')

l5=Label(window, text="Year end:")
l5.grid(row=7, column=1, sticky='E')

"""
Second and third titles - form beginning
"""


label_second_title=Label(window, text="Scoring Referance (enter only 1 number):", height=3, fg="blue")
label_second_title.grid(row=8, column=1, columnspan=2, sticky=W)

label_third_title=Label(window, text="Excellent: 10 | Good: 9 - 8 | Avarage: 7 - 6 | Poor: 0 - 5", height=3, fg="blue")
label_third_title.grid(row=9, column=1, columnspan=2, sticky=W)

empty_label=Label(window, text=" ", width=15)
empty_label.grid(row=9, column=0)

second_empty_label=Label(window, text=" ", width=15)
second_empty_label.grid(row=4, column=6)

#third_empty_label=Label(window, text="View Entry", height=3)
#third_empty_label.grid(row=26, column=1)


"""
Form level labels
"""

l6=Label(window, text="File presentation:")
l6.grid(row=10, column=1, sticky='E')

l7=Label(window, text="Quality of job processing")
l7.grid(row=11, column=1, sticky='E')

l8=Label(window, text="Queries and assumptions:")
l8.grid(row=12, column=1, sticky='E')

l9=Label(window, text="Indexing and cross referencing:")
l9.grid(row=13, column=1, sticky='E')

l10=Label(window, text="Final reports (draft accounts):")
l10.grid(row=14, column=1, sticky='E')

l11=Label(window, text="Documents handling / usage:")
l11.grid(row=15, column=1)

l12=Label(window, text="Meeting deadlines:")
l12.grid(row=16, column=1, sticky='E')

l13=Label(window, text="Communication:")
l13.grid(row=17, column=1, sticky='E')

l14=Label(window, text="Analytical review:")
l14.grid(row=18, column=1, sticky='E')

l15=Label(window, text="Overall Job rating:")
l15.grid(row=19, column=1, sticky='E')

l16=Label(window, text="Suggestion / Review:")
l16.grid(row=20, column=1, sticky='E')

l25=Label(window, text="@ A production of Shehan H.", fg="red")
l25.grid(row=30, column=6, sticky='E')

"""
Entry boxes top
"""

client_code_text=StringVar()
e1=Entry(window, textvariable=client_code_text)
e1.grid(row=4, column=2)


client_name_text=StringVar()
e2=Entry(window, textvariable=client_name_text)
e2.grid(row=4, column=4)





assignment_no_text=StringVar()
e3=Entry(window, textvariable=assignment_no_text)
e3.grid(row=5, column=2)

accountant_text=StringVar()
e4=Entry(window, textvariable=accountant_text)
e4.grid(row=6, column=2)

year_end_text=StringVar()
e5=Entry(window, textvariable=year_end_text)
e5.grid(row=7, column=2)

"""
Entry boxes form level
"""

file_presentation_text=StringVar()
e6=Entry(window, textvariable=file_presentation_text)
e6.grid(row=10, column=2)

quality_of_job_processed_text=StringVar()
e7=Entry(window, textvariable=quality_of_job_processed_text)
e7.grid(row=11, column=2)

queries_text=StringVar()
e8=Entry(window, textvariable=queries_text)
e8.grid(row=12, column=2)

indexing_text=StringVar()
e9=Entry(window, textvariable=indexing_text)
e9.grid(row=13, column=2)

final_reports_text=StringVar()
e10=Entry(window, textvariable=final_reports_text)
e10.grid(row=14, column=2)

documents_handling_text=StringVar()
e11=Entry(window, textvariable=documents_handling_text)
e11.grid(row=15, column=2)

meeting_deadlines_text=StringVar()
e12=Entry(window, textvariable=meeting_deadlines_text)
e12.grid(row=16, column=2)

communication_text=StringVar()
e13=Entry(window, textvariable=communication_text)
e13.grid(row=17, column=2)

analytical_review_text=StringVar()
e14=Entry(window, textvariable=analytical_review_text)
e14.grid(row=18, column=2)

overall_job_text=StringVar()
e15=Entry(window, textvariable=overall_job_text)
e15.grid(row=19, column=2)

suggestion_text=StringVar()
e16=Entry(window, textvariable=suggestion_text, width=50)
e16.grid(row=20, column=2, padx=5,pady=10,ipady=3)

"""
Buttons

"""
b1=Button(window, text="Submit to GI", width=12, command=add_entry_command)
b1.grid(row=25, column=2)

b2=Button(window, text="Export report", width=12, command=write_to_csv)
b2.grid(row=25, column=3)

b3=Button(window, text="Connect client", width=12)
b3.grid(row=4, column=5)

"""
List box to view results
Maight be deleted and changed with popup to confirm



list1=Listbox(window, height=1, width=70)
list1.grid(row=26, column=2)
"""

window.mainloop()
```

and this is the backend module

```
import sqlite3
import csv
import os
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import *


def connect():
    conn=sqlite3.connect("lite.db")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS gi_store (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, client_code_ text, client_name_  text, assignment_no_ text, accountant_ text,  year_end_ text, file_presentation_ integer, quality_of_job_processed_ integer, queries_ integer, indexing_ integer, final_reports_ integer, documents_handling_ integer, meeting_deadlines_ integer, communication_ integer, analytical_review_ integer, overall_job_ integer, suggestion_  text)")
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

def insert(client_code_, client_name_, assignment_no_, accountant_,  year_end_, file_presentation_, quality_of_job_processed_, queries_, indexing_, final_reports_, documents_handling_, meeting_deadlines_, communication_, analytical_review_, overall_job_, suggestion_):
    conn=sqlite3.connect("lite.db")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO gi_store VALUES(NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", (client_code_, client_name_, assignment_no_, accountant_,  year_end_, file_presentation_, quality_of_job_processed_, queries_, indexing_, final_reports_, documents_handling_, meeting_deadlines_, communication_, analytical_review_, overall_job_, suggestion_))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

def view():
    conn=sqlite3.connect("lite.db")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM gi_store")
    rows=cur.fetchall()
    conn.close()
    return rows

def write_to_csv():
    conn=sqlite3.connect("lite.db")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM gi_store")
    csvWriter = csv.writer(open("output.csv", "w", newline=''))

    rows = cur.fetchall()
    csvWriter.writerow(["ID", "Client Code", "Client Name", "Assignment number", "Accountant", "Year End", "File Presentation", "Quality of job processed", "Queries", "Indexing", "Final reports", "Doc. handling", "Meeting deadlines", "Communication", "Analytical review", "Overall rate", "Suggestion box"])
    for row in rows:
        # do your stuff
        csvWriter.writerow(row)

    conn.close()

def check_assignment(assignment_no_):
    conn=sqlite3.connect("lite.db")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    control_assignment = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM gi_store WHERE assignment_no_ = ?", (assignment_no_,))
    control_assignment_row=cur.fetchone()
    conn.close()
    return control_assignment_row

connect()

#print(check_assignment(assignment_no_text="2"))
```

Comment: `id` should be unique so maybe use `id` instead of `"Assignment number"`

Comment: Hi furas, thank you for your comment, the issue is that another company will give us the assignment no code that we want to put in this survey form. and this gui program will be used by 20 other people and i want to avoid them to put the same assignment number code by mistake. thank you

Comment: I see you use `check_assignment()` to check it - doesn't it work ? Do you get error ? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: use `print()` to see what you get from `check_assignment()` - it is  probably single row or `None` but you compare it with `0` - you should rather check `is not None` . OR you should use `SELECT COUNT(*)`  to get numer from database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your functions `check_assignment()` returns row with assignment number or `None` but you compare with `0`. You should compare with `None`

```
 if check_assignment(assignment_no_text.get()) is None:
```

Comment: THANK YOU very much Furas! It worked! You have been really helpfull, thank you again, have a nice weekend